# Two groups measured twice - which strategy is correct?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

I could need some help on how to choose the correct way to analyze the data I have collected.

I conducted an experiment with two groups (control condition vs. experimental condition). The continuous dependent variable was tested twice after the intervention for each subject. That is, I have one between subjects-factor (condition) and one within subjects-factor (test time). Additionally, I have one continuous control variable that ideally I would like to include in my model, but this is not a priority.

Basically, I would like to test the following hypothesis:

- Is there a difference between the two conditions at test time 1?
- Is the change between test time 1 and test time 2 different for the two conditions (interaction condition/test time)?

These are the ideas I have come up with:

**A hierarchical linear model/multilevel model**

...with time as a within subjects factor, condition as a between subjects factor and an interaction of both to analyze the change between test times 1 and 2.

Advantage: I can include my control variable and all hypothesis can be tested in one model.

Disadvantage: Is it correct? Plus, my supervisor/reviewer would prefer a more simple approach.

**A repeated measures ANOVA**

... again with time as a within subjects factor, condition as a between subjects factor and an interaction of both to analyze the change between test times 1 and 2.

Advantage: Similar to multilevel approach, I could include my control variable.

Disadvantage: I'm not sure if it is correct. Additionally, it may still be too complicated. And I would need to perform post-hoc analyses.

**Two t-tests**

One t-test for the difference between the two conditions at test time 1. Then I would calculate the difference between test time 1 and test time 2 and in a second t-test would test if this difference differs between the two conditions.

Advantage: "Simple". If I put the variables in an ANCOVA I could additionally control for my continuous variable.

Disadvantage: Wrong? Okay? I'm not sure about it.

**Summary**

I have to meet two demands: I want to analyze the data correctly and I have to do it as simple as possible. Thus, if it would be okay/correct to analyze the data with the two t-tests approach I would probably go for it, as my supervisor/reviewer would be happy with it. However, if it is not correct, I would be okay with one of the "more complicated" approaches, if I were at least sure that they are okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, I'm pretty sure that the correct way to analyze this kind of data is a multilevel regression model (https://neuropsychology.github.io/psycho.R/2018/05/01/repeated_measure_anovas.html). I chose a random intercept model where the intercept varies per subject (because each subject was observed twice) and included the treatment, time and control variable effects as fixed effects.